# How do I dynamically add text to a TSkLabel of different colors and sizes?

Tags: delphi, skia, skia4delphi

I have a `TSkLabel` on my form and I am able to add text of different colors and sizes to it during design-time, but how can I do this during run-time dynamically?

I know I need to somehow populate the `Word` property items, but I don't know how.

Can anyone help please?